# Building a restaurant site... How should I implement online ordering?

Tags: website-design, payments

I have been looking into different 3rd party solutions for this for some time now, and have been disappointed in that I cannot find a decent comparison of features, or really any recommendations at all.  I have managed to compile a list of different options I've found:

**3rd party hosted online ordering systems**

- http://www.menudrive.com/
- [http://onlineordering.com/](http://cafetech.net)
- http://cafetech.net
- http://www.ezwaiter.com/
- http://openmenu.com/
- http://www.compelcart.com/
- https://www.opendining.net (has WP & FB plugins)
- http://pizzagalaxy.com/
- http://www.edcinteractive.com/
- http://www.mealclick.com

I've found that the majority of these look absolutely horrid, and do not provide the ability to edit the layout (or even the css).  I really just want something someone can order a pizza with, and have it be relatively seamless, maintaining the look of the site

Comment: Can't you compare the features yourself? I'm sure most of these sites list their features or otherwise have sales staff you can ask about the features or a demo/tour of their product.

Comment: I can, and will.  I guesse my hope was that someone had previous experience with these, or other such services... and might be able to save me (and fellow webdevs) some time and energy.  I am sure this list is far from comprehensive, and hope that I missed some of the best ones - because in general I am underwhelmed with the choices.

Comment: I've come across some services/companies in related niches, but not the exact thing you're looking for, so I can't help here. But it sounds to me like there could be an opportunity for you to fill an underserved niche. If you've evaluated all the options on the market right now and find no acceptible solutions, then you would be primed to develop your own product/service, as you've basically already done your market research. You know what the client's needs are, and you know what's missing from existing offerings; so create a solution that fills the void.

Comment: I still need to go down the list and properly evaluate each of these.  When complete, I'll post my findings here.

Comment: @Lèse This does sound like a good project - unfortunately I have too many of those right now ;-).  I'll put it in the queue.  For this job the timeframe is such that a sub-optimal solution will have to be good enough

Comment: Are you using a CMS for the site, if so which one?

Comment: It's still in the planning/design phase.  Therefore, I am flexible as to what CMS (if any) I use.  I was considering WordPress since I have some experience with it, but also considering trying something new on this project.

Answer (score 1):

As a consumer I always order my pizza online if the option is available. Most of the time the sites are terrible. I would recommend building your own solution and keep it as simple as possible.

It terms of a great experience look at the Pizza Hut app (I use it on Android) it is extremely well done.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you could achieve with a standard shopping cart rather than a customised food specific service?

Also have you considered services like just-eat.co.uk?

Answer (score -1):

Put your phone number in the header, ensure someone of your men is always ready to answer that phone and have luck with your business ;)

Comment: i wonder, why e-commerce 'experts' fail to accept the fact that so many people use **phone** to order cheap everyday stuff like taxi, or pizza.

Comment: I don't think that's really the case.  Including the phone number prominently is a pretty obvious and easy thing to do.  I would be very surprised if any "e-commerce experts" think that an online ordering system would be more popular than the phone.  The process of implementing a phone number would generally require less technical know-how, and thus would not appear as prominently on sites such as SO.